# Can we Send Custom Error MEssages

Tags: community, email, approval-process

Can we change the below message which we get  when We try to Reject a custom object record Without giving Comments and we have written a trigger to allow only those records where Comments are provided if user is providing Comments and Rejecting?

> An error occurred and your workflow approval message was not processed. Please contact your system administrator.

Comment: Are you trying to send custom error message in approval process ?

Comment: When user rejects the approval request through email and without comments then he receives the above error as he didnot put comments while rejection.

Comment: No this is the automatic mail received from salesforce when user tries to reject the approval request through email and forgot to put comments which we have made mandatory by writting trigger